# Multivariable integration by substitution Part $2$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, substitution

> Note: There is a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223573/multivariable-integration-by-substitution) with same title but the contents are entirely different.

Integration by substitution says:

$$\int^{r(b)}_{r(a)} f(r)dr=\int ^b_a f[r(x)] \dfrac{dr(x)}{dx}dx$$

where $f$ is a function of $r$ and $r$ is a function of $x$.

Now if $f$ is a function of $r$ and $r$ is a multivariable function of $x$ and $y$, are the following true:?

$$\int^{r(b,b')}_{r(a,a')}f(r)dr=\int ^b_a f[r(x,y)] \dfrac{\partial r(x,y)}{\partial x}dx=\int^{b'}_{a'}  f[r(x,y)] \dfrac{\partial r(x,y)}{\partial y}dy$$

where $a$ and $b$ are lower and upper limits of $x$; $a'$ and $b'$ are lower and upper limits of $y$

Comment: The limits of integration, $r(a), r(b)$ make no sense, since $r$ is a function of two variables.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on this.

As @saulspatz eluded to in their comment, *explicitly* solving the *definite* integral in the way you suggest doesn't make sense as when integrating w.r.t. $x$ you don't know how to evaluate $y$ and vice versa.

However, I believe your relation *does* hold if you first calculate the *indefinite* integrals by integrating w.r.t. $x$ or $y$, and then sub back in for $r$ at the end, and evaluate the limits.

**Example**

For a simple example, say we want to solve

$$ \int_{0}^{1} r^2 \mathrm{d}r = \frac{1}{3}$$ (n.b. $\int r^2 \mathrm{d}r = \frac{r^3}{3} + c$) 
using the multivariable substitution $r^2 = x^2+y^2$. Then
$$ \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} = \frac{x}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}, \quad \frac{\partial r}{\partial y} = \frac{y}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}.  $$
So according to the *indefinite* version of your stated formula we get
$$ \int r^2 \mathrm{d}r = \int (x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} x \mathrm{d}x =  \int (x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} y \mathrm{d}y, $$
The latter two integrals evaluate to $\frac{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3} + c$, which then gives $\frac{r^3}{3} + c$ after substituting for $r$. The *definite* value of the integral can then be calculated by evaluating the integration limits with $r=0$ and $r=1$ to get the answer $\frac{1}{3}$.